# @ExceptionHandler for Wrapped Exception / getCause() in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Does anyone know the best/simplest way to use `@ExceptionHandler` for wrapped Exceptions?

I have a custom `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter` that I use for converting a `@PathVariable` and it throws a custom runtime exception if the input is outside a standard range.

This winds up being wrapped in a `ConversionException` by Spring, which I can handle with `@ExceptionHandler(ConversionException.class)` in my Controller Advice.

However I have to `.getCause()` and use `instanceof` to determine if the underlying exception is the type I'm interested in.  At that point I can use the response to `.sendError()` but in the case where I have a different underlying exception I'm not sure what to do?

If I rethrow the original exception I get a nasty log message 'Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method', and it doesn't feel right.

Is there an easy way to do something like `@ExceptionHandler(MyCustomConversionException.class`) where `MyCustomConversionException` is the cause of the `ConversionException`  in the `@ControllerAdvice`?

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Create a ControllerAdvice class `@ControllerAdvice` which would allow you to create multiple `@ExceptionHandler` entries. Each method can reference a single exception or multiple exceptions.

for example:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController extends ResponseExceptionHanlder {
  @ExceptionHandler(value = { NumberFormatException.class })
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNumberFormatExcpetion(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
     //TODO: Handle exception
     return handleExceptionInternal(ex, 'error', new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(value = { InvalidClassException.class })
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNumberFormatExcpetion(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
     //TODO: Handle exception
     return handleExceptionInternal(ex, 'error', new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(value = { MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class,  SizeLimitExceededException.class })
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNumberFormatExcpetion(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
     //TODO: Handle exception
     return handleExceptionInternal(ex, 'error', new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is just how to setup a standard @ControllerAdvice class, what I'm asking about is how to handle exceptions that are **wrapped** in other exceptions.

Comment: Actually, sorry I see what you're doing there, I think the base class should be ResponseEntityExceptionHandler, I'll look into it thank you!

Comment: It's not really clear what this answer is doing and how it answers the question. It doesn't even compile.

Comment: It's pretty clear what it does. It handles multiple thrown exception. It doesn't compile because it's a snippet and it's up to the OP to implement it based of their needs.

Comment: This answer is wrong -- it doesn't capture Wrapped Exceptions, I just tried it and didn't get to my handler.

Comment: @geneb. it works fine. I've used this across all my mvc projects without issues. it all depends on your implementation of it.