# Spring ExceptionHandler for Caused By / Wrapped Exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception

I couldn't find a good solution: In my Spring Boot app, as an `@ExceptionHandler` method, I need to define a handler not for a specific exception, but for any exception ***caused by*** a specific exception (i.e. a wrapped exception).

Example: Sometimes I get this:

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:541) ~[spring-orm-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746) ~[spring-tx-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]    
    ... 121 common frames omitted
Caused by: custom.TechRoleException: My custom TechRoleException
    at myapp.method1[..]
    at myapp.methodOuter[..]
```

My custom `TechRoleException` is an exception I throw inside some Hibernate EventListener's pre-update method, and the direct exception is that Persistence couldn't occur.

However, the following method that tries to use my custom exception is never reached:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(TechRoleException.class)
  public String techRoleException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Got here");
    return "home";
  }
}
```

Here's a similar thread where the answer is wrong and didn't answer this question:
[@ExceptionHandler for Wrapped Exception / getCause() in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50531242/exceptionhandler-for-wrapped-exception-getcause-in-spring)

Comment: Is the ControllerAdvice not working at all or just in some cases?

Comment: Just not working for the Caused-By, working in all other cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My final working answer is to handle a **General** Exception, and then use [Apache](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.7/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils.html) `ExceptionUtils.getRootCause()` to detect the specific Caused-By I'm looking for within this general handler.

(Other specific Exceptions won't come to this method if they have their dedicated Handlers. But if there's no dedicated Handler, the exception will come here.) This is the only way to detect some target Caused-By.

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public String handleGeneralException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex) {

    Throwable rootCause = ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(ex);
    if (rootCause != null && "com.myapp.TechRoleException".equals(rootCause.getClass().getName())
    {       
        //... handle this Caused-By Exception here
        // ...
    }
    // All other exceptions that don't have dedicated handlers can also be handled below...
    // ...

}
```

Comment: But is it not possible to avoid that TransactionSystemException. What does it makes sense to have a global exception handler, when we get wrapped the exception with this one?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like that?

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public String techRoleException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex) {
if(ex instanceof TechRoleException) {
    System.out.println("Got here");
    return "home";
} else {
    throw ex; //or something else
}
}
```

Comment: Please do not use Throwable in this case unless you want to also catch assertion Errors. Use Exception.

Comment: Yes that works. I don't even need to "throw ex" for others, because other dedicated handlers for specific Exceptions skip this method.

Comment: I thought about this and I don't know how it works :D I'm not sure but i think we should use: if(ex.getCause() instanceof TechRoleException). Or eventually use Apache library method - Throwable getRootCause(Throwable throwable) for get the rootCause and then check instanceof. What do you think? If application throw exception (TransactionSystemException), how instanceof with TechRoleException can give us true? I think we should use ex.getCause() or this apache library to find root cause. Check it if you want

Comment: Yes I used Apache ExceptionUtils getRootCause(). I'll post a complete answer.